Does anyone know what the horizontal switch on the white enclosure does?
It is in a condo and my guess is that it turns on and off the water, but l've never seen something like this before:


What country is this in?

why don't you try it? ... see what it does ... there is no reason to be guessing

Now that this is solved, you should turn your attention to the leaky dryer vent! :)

Yes, it's a washer on-off valve. See photo below from Arbor, who I am not affiliated with.

https://superarbor.io/products/202269939-laundry-mate-1-2-in-brass-concealed-washing-machine-valve?currency=USD&variant=46905460982075&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Google%20Shopping&stkn=02af43b4f156&srsltid=AfmBOorQ8GZ0pJiZaudOKYrPJPP_6fVwR-IVGdIC3Z5FdfYoPdvvFJwMEYg

Jack good find!  Here's a link to the manufacturer's page that you could use instead.   Turns out this is a current line of boxes.  Rebuildable brass valve above and strong metal bottom, just a high quality (and expensive) version of the one everyone buys at big hardware stores.

I have never seen that type either.  But your guess is right.
I imagine it is because washer hoses should not be pressurize all the time(they have a nasty habit of bursting) and a simple one switch to turn off the water would help people who get tired turning off two taps all the time.
A nice simple swipe instead of turning and turning taps.

A dis and a dat mixed up like a peanut  butter cup.

Wahay!  Here's one with cloud services

@jay613   I like the brass one a lot better for ten percent of the cost.  Nice, simple, and probably will last forever or much longer than the one with cloud service.
